# Horizontal scrolling in selenium web driver till element is not visible

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a website that has a long horizontal table. I have Xpath that extracts column headers of a table that stretches more than the screen width (3X of the screen width). Now I have to extract all column heads with their respective index as my table has show columns filters from where user can select or deselect the rows. So I need to dynamically fetch the columns with the index. Now I when I try to fetch the column heads for the first time then system fetch me the column heads till it is visible on the first screen without scroll but now when the system tries to get the column head which is not visible on chrome then code returns a null value.

1. I have tried to get the total number of columns and checked that scrolling right by 8 columns will do my job but then with this, I am not able to reuse this function on other web tables where there are lesser columns as the system does not find the i+8 column and shows the exception.
2. I tried to scroll right every time by one column when I get column head as blank. But with this, my code has to check one if condition each time when it does get blank and this is making my method very slow which I can't afford as I need to get at least 35 columns and that too more than 2-3 time in bigger methods.

Now, what I know here is I know which is the last column head was visible to me so I need to scroll right till column head which I had is not visible to me on a screen which other way means I have scrolled maximum to right without hiding the column which I haven't covered. How can I do it?

This is what I tried for this scrolling by 8 columns by seeing the general width of columns. This is working for me but restricting the reusability of function.

```
if (colHead.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
WebElement elementToBeScrolled1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th["+i+"+8]"));
By elementToBeScrolled = getByLocator(elementToBeScrolled1);
        do {
          keyPress(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT);
        } while (waitForElement(elementToBeScrolled, 5, WaitType.invisibilityOfElementLocated));
        colHead = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[" + i + "]"))
            .getText();
```

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: 1. This is for the 1st logic where I tried to scroll by 8 columns:   if (colHead.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        WebElement elementToBeScrolled1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[" + i + "+8]"));
        By elementToBeScrolled = getByLocator(elementToBeScrolled1);
        do {
          keyPress(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT);
        } while (waitForElement(elementToBeScrolled, 5, WaitType.invisibilityOfElementLocated));
        colHead = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[" + i + "]"))
            .getText();

Comment: Instead of updating through comments, update the main question with all the relevant details.

Comment: Done that.@DebanjanB